# Compact Framework file Upload via FTP

Tags: c#, upload, ftp, opennetcf

Does anybody know any FTP package that is working correctly under .NET 2.0 Compact Framework? 
I've tried:

- OpennNetCF
- 32feet's In The Hand: they are same, 530 return code
- ftp24cp: desktop version works w/ active but does not works in
  passive mode

My ftp server is simple ftp w/ default port, username and password. I can do all with Total Commander even passive or active mode. DOS version ftp also working fine, I can upload anything via command line.
All of the above packages connecting fine but the upload attempt gives error.

In the code:

- setting new ftp object
- set the connected event to my own handler
- set credentials
- connect
- in connected event handler start the upload
- close connection

Any help I can get is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what kind of error does it actually give you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is (commercial) SecureBlackbox library, which supports FTP (and lot of other stuff) for .NET CF 2.0, check it out.
Unfortunately, I do not know any other free/opensource alternatives.